# Trying to integrate the volume of a body

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I was trying to integrate the volume of a body blocked by $z=0$, $z=2x$, $x+y=3$ and $y=0$ using the double integral... but I don't really know how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: First sketch a graph of the solid. The find the limits of integration over one of the variables, say $z$ and then project the solid onto the plane perpenducular to it, in this case it will be the $x-y$ plane.

So, notice that $z$ goes from $0$ to $2x$. This is the "roof" of your solid and your integral will look like

$\int_{d}^{e}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{0}^{2x}dzdydx$

Now, projecting onto the $x-y$ plane, you get the plane region given by

$2x=0\Rightarrow x=0\\y=3-x\\y=0$

so you now do an easy double integral over this region, from which you can determine $a,b,d,e$. $a$ and $b$ may of course, be functions of $x$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: very helpful, thanks!